# adding functions to self made calculator

Tags: function, python-3.x, math, calculator

Ok so I'm trying to make a working napier numeral calculator. I have gone through most of the steps I need to make it work. I need 2 more steps the function and converting it back to napier numbers. Currently I'm stuck on getting the functions to work. It just seems to skip that step. From what I can tell it should work and not be skipped. Could anyone tell me if I missed a step in the process of making the function.

```
    def main():
    response = 'y'
    while response == 'y' or response == 'Y':
        nap1 = getNapier()
        num1 = napToInt(nap1)        
        print(num1)
        nap2 = getNapier()
        num2 = napToInt(nap2)
        print(num1, num2)
        operator = getOperator
        result = doMath(num1, num2, operator)



        response = input("Try another[y/n]")
def doMath(num1, num2, operator):
    if operator == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
    elif operator == "*":
        answer = num1 * num2
    else:
        if operator == "/":
            answer = num1 / num2
    return doMath
def getOperator():
    op = input("Enter operator: ")
    while op not in "+-*/":
        op = input("Error!!!! Enter operator: ")
    return op
def napToInt(n):
    result = 0
    for ch in n:
        result += 2 ** (ord(ch) - ord('a'))
    return result
def getNapier():
    nap = input("Enter Napier number: ")
    while not nap.isalpha():
        nap = input("Error!!! Enter Napier number: ")
    return nap
main()
```

this is the result I get as you can see it gets the napier numbers and just stops

```
 Enter Napier number: asdf
262185
Enter Napier number: adsf
262185 262185
Try another[y/n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line `operator = getOperator` should be `operator = getOperator()`

Comment: well I'm an idiot thank you for pointing that out hahaha I'll accept your answer when it lets me